# Loopholes that are forbidden by default

Tags: discussion, faq, policy, answers, defaults

There are a number of standard loopholes which experienced question-setters seek to explicitly close. However, inexperienced question-setters may unintentionally leave them open, or respondents may try to argue for contorted interpretations of the question in order to side-step attempts to close them.

The purpose of this question is to provide a repository of standard loopholes which may be assumed to be closed without the question-setter having to explicitly close them. The intention is that each answer shall contain one and only one loophole (to allow independent voting); and that the loophole described in any answer which is at +5 or above and has at least twice as many upvotes as downvotes may be taken to be deemed to be unacceptable to the community. A link to that answer may be provided in a comment to accompany [a downvote and a flag](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7990).

[Return to FAQ index](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1280)

Comment: Loopholes are part of what makes the game interesting. Even common ones can be funny or clever, depending on context. If you find a loophole in an answer disinteresting, don’t vote for it, or vote against it. I don’t think we need a canonical list of fun things that you can’t do. (With the exception of **Interpreting the challenge too literally** below. That’s always boring. `;)`)

Comment: @minitech: And the [countless variations](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny/1062#1062) of `curl -L http://bit.ly/012foobar` aren't?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Depends whether it’s actually clever. If you don’t find it clever, vote appropriately. As always.

Comment: @minitech, there seems to be a strong consensus that the appropriate vote is "Low quality, delete".

Comment: "at least twice as many upvotes as downvotes" ... You can't see that until you have at least 750 rep on the site. Seems like the rules should be visible to everyone.

Comment: @derobert, I don't want to be seen to claim that a 105 vs 100 voting situation represents a clear community consensus, and I think that looking for a supermajority is the best way to avoid that. It's unfortunate that the score breakdown isn't visible to everyone, but I don't generally expect many low-rep users to visit meta. FWIW, the only current answer which doesn't have a supermajority is "Using comments to circumvent character requirements/restrictions" on +11/-6.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Ah. I'm surprised "Using the program name to store data" isn't one of them, considering the +26 comment on it.

Comment: @derobert, it's at +28/-4. Very puzzling. My best guess is that most of the people upvoting the answer agreed with the part of the comment which says that the filename should be counted towards the length of the program.

Comment: The condition for whether the loophole applies should probably be changed to +10 or +15. All of the answers are currently above the +5 mark due to the surge in popularity of this post. Perhaps it could be a moving window (all answers with a score of `average of all answer scores / 2` or `the score of the highest voted answer / 5` or something), but that would be pretty complicated.

Comment: It's nice that this is in the FAQ, but I can find no obvious way to get to the FAQ so that new users can see it. I don't think we should be downvoting users for breaking a rule they don't know about. The FAQ needs to be easily available to new users who get her via any means.

Comment: When I say it is "no obvious way to get to the FAQ", I am referring to the fact that it does not seem to be linked in the Help dropdown itself nor mentioned in the Tour or Help Center pages. I know I only found out about this page after I saw a question that downvoted because of it. (And because it was mentioned explicitly in some questions, but those keep being removed.)

Answer (score 465):

### Interpreting the challenge too literally

That is, if the challenge says "write a function that, given a number *n*, returns the *n*-th prime", posting something equivalent to:

```
function f($n) {
    return "the $n-th prime";
}
```

Comment: I believe you meant "Compiling the challenge too literally" :P

Comment: @Jwosty not in this case, as PHP is interpreted.

Comment: @Rokk Or is it? IT'S ALL A RUSE!

Comment: Someone may answer my question, I've said this a few months ago (http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/924/this-kind-of-answer-print-a-s-by-s-box-n ), but why does my question have a tag "this question has already been answered in {this topic}"? Even though my own one was months prior to this one? I didn't think it would be like that.

Comment: Your example is actually one of not interpreting the challenge quite literally enough. You would have a good point if this were a spoken medium, but on a typed challenge, "the $n-th prime" in quotes is different from "the $n-th prime" without the quotes.
Punctuation matters. It's the difference between "I had a dream about 3 ballerinas, Stalin, Mussolini, and Hitler." and "I had a dream about 3 ballerinas: Stalin, Mussolini, and Hitler."

Comment: This is not a loophole actually. It's just a misconception (albeit a very extended one), a confusion between [use and mention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction). The challenge didn't include quotation marks

Comment: @LuisMendo: It could also be viewed as a representation issue. That is, if we accept, say, "13", "13.0", "thirteen", "XIII", "0xD" and "1.3e1" as valid representations of the same number, then *why not* also "10 + 3" or "int(pi^2 + pi)" or "x: x^2 - 26*x + 169 = 0" or "the 6th prime"? This is not a trivial issue in philosophy of mathematics, since in math, we're *constantly* dealing with numbers that we can't write down as, say, a finite sequence of decimals, like pi or sqrt(2) or even just 1/3. Just about the only *easy and simple* answer is "because it would make the challenge boring".

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I tend to agree with your reasoning. But for the _n_-th prime there _is_ a convenient decimal representation, whereas for the cases you mention there is not. Saying "sqrt(2)" is probably the simplest explicit representation of the intended number, whereas saying "the _n_-th prime" is not (you could write it explicitly and simply as "23", or as "127", etc)

Comment: `"the $n-th prime"` is **not** the n-th prime.

Comment: @Jwosty I think you're interpreting the answer too literally.

Comment: @Khaled.K: Exactly. It is ridiculous that people on CG SE do not understand the difference between strings and their evaluation (if any).

Answer (score 385):

### Fetching the desired output from an external source

This includes doing an HTTP request to fetch the page with the question and extracting a solution from that page. This was mildly amusing back in 2011, but now is derivative and uninteresting.

Comment: Especially getting the highest voted answer from the selected wuestion

Comment: We could allow it, if the size of the external source is added to the size of the answer.

Comment: You mean a `copy-paste` answer?

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer, no, I mean an answer which saves bytes by replacing a large string with a `wget` or similar that fetches it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I see; well if the content that the solution depends on is retrieved from a source that is not part of the platform, then its size has to be added to the size of the answer. I don't see a difference between manually copy-paste or make a wget do the copy-paste.

Comment: some [tag:internet] questions may need to do so, but source code itself still not allowed to just be fetched

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23968/59169 is an excellent example how this can be used creatively

Comment: @val, not really. It could have been golfed considerably by self-hosting a page with just the desired content and, if necessary, using a URL shortener. And that's really the point: outsourcing the output gives you arbitrary text at a fixed byte count.

Answer (score 332):

### Using a made-up language specifically designed for the challenge

This includes any language with commands that ["do whatever I choose them to do"](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humpty_Dumpty#Lewis_Carroll%27s_Through_the_Looking-Glass).  Claiming that your answer is written in "MyOwnLanguage", where the command `x` means "read a sequence of numbers, split them into groups of three, and print the last numbers of those groups where the second number is less than the first", was clever [the first time it was done](http://esolangs.org/wiki/HQ9%2B).  That was a *long* time ago.

Comment: I think `HQ9+` should no longer be considered made up. It's useless for almost all challenges, and [can sometimes be used creatively](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21839/3544).

Comment: Sorry, I agree with the poster.  Makes for boring answers.  The question it was used to answer could have been a lot more exciting and interesting without the trolly languages and GolfScript.

Comment: -1: if a question can be answered creatively with HQ9+ or any other language that was already existing before the challenge was posted, then maybe the question was boring and not the answer.

Comment: Could this be split in two answers? I would vote up for “made-up language” but not for HQ9+. And given this answer has the most mixed votes (+13/-7), maybe I'm not the only with similar opinion.

Comment: @manatwork: I originally included the mention of HQ9+ because I was (and still am) kind of tired of people invariably trying to use it for each and every [tag:hello-world] and [tag:quine] challenge, *even those where it fails to meet the spec*. But you're right, it's been around long enough to become sort of established. I've edited this answer not to mention HQ9+, except tangentially as a "historical example". I haven't posted a separate "using HQ9+" answer, since I honestly don't see it as that much of an issue in itself; if anyone else wants to do so, feel free.

Comment: I'd bound this in with "get from external source" and other ways of hiding byte count.

Comment: I don't have any problem with made-up languages. But the language should already exist when the challenge was posted. Never versions of the language are not allowed (to prevent changing the language e.g adding an extra command to HQ9+).

Comment: Where to draw the line between “made up” languages and languages which are not made up for one specific challenge but still are not really used outside of codegolf (or similar) challenges? Does using a language for two challenges already qualify?

Comment: @Holger: Nowadays, from what I've seen, the general consensus seems to be that any language (version) released before the challenge started (or was first proposed in the sandbox, etc.) is OK. That is, the important point is that the language should not be made up *for the challenge*.

Comment: This standard loophole also closes the possibility of saying "since all Turing-computable programs are enumerable (and therefore representable as a number -- say, a compiled binary interpreted as a binary number), I hereby define a family of languages, *MyLang-`N`*, where each MyLang-`N` correspond to a language where the empty string executes the `N`th program in the enumeration of all programs."

Comment: To anyone else who is looking for the more exact rule "the language should be released before the question was posted": it was given [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10/25180).

Comment: Isn't that just called "a golfing language"?

Comment: MetaGolfScript is a notable one.

Answer (score 246):

Using lots of spaces to "hide" code out of bounds, especially in [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded) questions. This isn't very clever or tricky, in my opinion, and yet wins all too often.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL)); // Make sure to seed rand so it's VERY random, we want to make super sure that it's very random! Otherwise the program is useless!
    int r = rand() % 6 + 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                              r = 5; // Sneaky sneaky!
    printf("Here is your TOTALLY random dice roll: %d",r);
}
```

Comment: I haven't even seen this before, do you have some examples? I actually think that is *so* lame I can't imagine it getting a lot of upvotes even without it being on this list.

Comment: @m.buettner http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28786/write-a-program-that-makes-2-2-5#28889
http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12291/ill-time-your-function-but-i-dont-work-weekends/12329#12329

Comment: ugh, have an upvote.

Comment: This is why I set all my editors to show whitespace.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Ugh, have an upvote on your comment about having an upvote.

Comment: It should be `r = 4`.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd for that last comment: https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: I've seen such trick in malware scripts in 90s. mIRC, an IRC client, was configurable with scripts that would add functionality. A way to do it was by creating the file script.ini in mIRC's main folder. Earlier versions of mIRC would use its main folder as a default download folder (when another user sends you a file), with the default option to accept a download automatically if the filename doesn't exist. So sending script.ini malware was quite popular. I had collected a few and the trick in this answer was used in some of them.

Comment: [underhanded] is dead, so should this be deleted?

Comment: It'll be easy to discover if the `VERY random number` is always 5

Comment: So we don't count characters when scrutineering ?

Answer (score 183):

## Using the program name to store data without counting those bytes

Example - this bash script prints `Hello World!`

```
echo $0
```

Must be saved in a file called `Hello World!`.

---

When using the filename to store data, add them as extra bytes to your solution similarly to any non-standard parameter.

For example the correct byte count for the above is 7 (`echo $0`) + 12 (`Hello World!`) = 19 bytes.

Comment: -1 I think this is completely fine, but if you are using the filename, then it **has to** count to the bytecount as well, just like any other non-standard parameter you have to specify in the command line / shebang.

Comment: @SztupY It's absolutely standard for the filename to be the first parameter. `argv[0]` is the filename in C for example.

Comment: It's quite standard for C executable to be named `a.out`. Can it be used without increasing bytes count?

Comment: @SztupY: I fixed this answer to allow using the filename, but only disallow failure to count those bytes.  Your comment had 224 upvotes, but the answer only 113 upvotes (and 26 downvotes) before I fixed it.  I reversed my vote after fixing it :P

Comment: Also, turns out `!` instead of `\!` works too, with bash.  History expansion doesn't apply to the results of parameter expansion, only to literal `!`.  (And is off by default in non-interactive shells anyway.)  So this example is badly golfed, but I'll leave in the `\!` as a hint/clue about what's going on.

Comment: @PeterCordes, there was no intention to golf the file name, because its bytes are not supposed to be counted. Space needs to be quoted in a line such as `cat > Hello\ World\!`, but indeed the created file name won't contain a `\`.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that it only became an issue once I changed the answer.  I updated it try to avoid the distraction of a sub-optimally-golfed implementation for future readers of the question, who aren't thinking about what it used to say.  Your point about `cat` is a reason to leave both the back-slashes in, so it creates `'Hello Word!'` for people that copy-paste the filename into a shell command without quoting it.  Ugh, I'd rather just assume that people know how to use quote filenames in the shell, but if you want to change it back to 21 bytes, I don't object.

Comment: What if relying on a necessary part as storage? e.g. a BAT file use its whole filename"1.BAT" to do operations, count as +1 or +5?

Comment: @l4m2: What happens if I name it `1.cmd`?

Comment: @SamB Discuss both situation

Comment: All answers I have recently looked at took command line arguments for granted without counting them towards the length.
The problem lies in the definition here. If you ask for a program `f(x) = y`, and provide test values for `x`, then `x` obviously doesn't count. "Hello World" however is `f() = x`. Writing a program `f(x) = x` is not the same. So the _real_ loophole is "defining would-be constants as variables to outsource them", which is the generalized form of multiple loopholes mentioned here.

Comment: It should just be 12. The backslash in the filename doesn't really exist on disk.

Comment: This is not right. If the filename contains the backslash, it will be present in the output too. If it doesn't it will not be. How the filename has to be entered in the shell is not the same as what the filename actually is. (if it's about counting the bytes needed to input it to the shell, the post should say that instead.) Also, if you were to actually create such a file, you'd need to escape or quote the space, but not the bang. (None of the shells that support history substitution trigger on a trailing `!`.) E.g. `touch 'Hello World!'`, or `touch Hello\ World!` both work.

Comment: Funny is that 286 users likes your comment, but only 24 people dislike the answer :P

Comment: Is it ok to require a certain filename, even when it is not used to store data? One example would be this bash script named 0 `$1||exec 0 $(($1-1))` which calls itself with a lower argument (recursive) till it reaches 0. Do i have to count the script name or not?

Answer (score 176):

### Outsourcing the real answer

I still did not see people using this thing here in serious answers (just in some jokes ones), but already saw it being used seriously elsewhere. To circumvent restrictions and rules in the question (normally size), the answerer writes a small program that downloads the real program from elsewhere and then compiles and runs it.

A variant of this is posting an answer that takes input from the user and then submits it to somewhere on the Internet that is responsible for solving the problem and send back the output.

Comment: +1: I think this can also be considered a link-only answer, and be flagged as such. I especially hate when answer like this appears in non code-golf questions, where they have absolutely no purpose.

Comment: @SztupY But much of the time, they aren't link only answer. They in fact do contain some working running code.

Comment: I'd lump this together with [Fetching the desired output from an external source](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1062). Fetching the *code* instead of the output from an external source doesn't really make it any more acceptable.

Comment: I agree with Ilmari - fetch code and fetch answer are two sides of the same coin. A very low-valued coin.

Comment: I think all networking should be banned unless explicitly allowed in the question..

Comment: A variant of this loophole is abusing an input-flexibility rule like "you can read the input in any format" to submit a program that evals the first line of input and requires, as part of the input format, that the input begin with a line containing a real program solving the problem.

Answer (score 143):

### Hard-coding the output

Unless the question is an obvious exception (the primary exception being those tagged [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)), your program is expected to do work, not just print a pre-calculated result. If the question doesn't require input and so a solution which just prints the answer would seem to meet the spec, downvote the question rather than post a protest answer consisting of the literal output.

Comment: Often, this vulnerability is an indicator of a dumb question...

Comment: Sometimes you can't solve a problem in any other way, e.g. [Factorial calculation without recursion/loops/eval](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12982/calculate-the-factorial-of-a-number-without-using-recursion-or-loops/12989#12989) - but that indicates a bad question.

Comment: How does [Bubblegum](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum) fit into this? It seems to be designed to kill pure [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] questions.

Comment: @CJDennis *Unless the question is an obvious exception (the primary exception being those tagged [tag:kolmogorov-complexity])*

Comment: Most questions provide a couple of test cases and not only one. Only a bad question would have this problem and even then, you could edit it.

Comment: Now I can't understand what this loophole means. Mr.Xcoder recently posted [this chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42240582#42240582) which [doesn't seem to be correct](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42240902#42240902). If the question requires input, hardcoding is impossible. Can you explain more? @PeterTaylor

Comment: @user202729, it was addressed at questions like "Write a program to output the smallest three-digit prime", where the GolfScript program `101` would almost certainly beat any program in any language which actually did work.

Comment: And as specified in the answer, it's better to downvote such challenges. Thanks.

Comment: I fell it's not a loophole to answers, but a requirement to questions

Comment: Is `f=n=>[1,7,31,105,300,754,1712,3576,6975,12871][n]` valid for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170437/when-in-rome-count-as-romans-do ?

Answer (score 140):

## Fake random numbers

Pretty much any [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded) challenge involving random numbers will have someone post this one:

```
int getRandomNumber()
{
   return 4;   //chosen by fair dice roll.
               //guaranteed to be random.
}
```

It was funny when [Randall Munroe did it](http://xkcd.com/221/) 7 years ago, not anymore. It has been used in [many challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=guaranteed+to+be+random.), some even [multiple times](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=Chosen+by+fair+dice+roll.) in the *same* challenge.

Comment: Can I assume you're not including [seeding a PRNG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23859/14215) to force a known sequence? I see that as related, but different.

Comment: @Geobits: Correct, I am not including seeding the PRNG in this one.

Comment: This works the same in **any** challenge type. When the challenge looks for a random number, there needs to be some randomness.

Comment: Strange that 100% of those rolls resulted in four... Not so random or fair, eh?

Comment: Related to that, I'm also sick of that comic being referred to so often.

Comment: Actually is random number generator, just P(4)=1.

Comment: @duran: No, it is P(x)=4 for all x in reals with probability 1, therefore it is not random but completely deterministic.

Comment: But a constant is a [random variable too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution)! :D

Comment: Someone's gotta make a language that takes 4 as a random call, or maybe one that has randomly mutating constants.

Comment: I think someone doesn't get it. The chance of rolling a 4 _on any single throw_ is the same as any other number. It's only when you roll it many times that it becomes _increasingly unlikely, but not impossible_ to get 4 every time. In fact, for _n_ rolls, any specific sequence of _n_ results is equally likely.

Comment: @CJDennis: There is no dice, there is only 4. It is 4 for all eternity, so it's not particularly random. But that's irrelevant to the fact that it's [*played out*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=played+out). So I think, if anyone, it is *you* who doesn't get it.

Comment: The XKCD comic was funny. The first person to actually use this was not funny (and every person thereafter). But you can't prove that a sequence of all 4s was not generated randomly without examining the code as it is a valid (but incredibly unlikely) sequence.

Comment: @CJDennis: The comic *was* funny when it was written 8 years ago. It's not funny anymore. Hence, it being added to the "loopholes that are forbidden by default." And since we're *displaying* code here, your last sentence appears to be a complete non sequitur.

Comment: Randall Munroe, and [Scott Adams](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25)

Comment: [underhanded] is dead, so should this be deleted?

Comment: @EsolangingFruit considering the "many challenges" leads to some *not* in the underhanded tag, I'd say yes it should stay. But if you feel strongly enough, I DGaF if you do delete it.

Comment: @KyleKanos I guess this applies to many [popcon]s, so I guess you should keep it.

Comment: I presume that the programmer rolls a dice during writing and that was the roll? Yes, it took a random number of tries?

Comment: @Willtech not sure what you mean; it's a direct copy-paste fron a webcomic, so no rolls or trials involved, just copying.

Answer (score 139):

## Copying an (unimproved) answer from elsewhere

If it's not your own work, and you can't even try enough to golf or improve it, then it's not yours to post.

Comment: +1, although this *could* be argued to be acceptable if you really think the answer is optimal and cannot be improved. It might be good form to mark the answer as Community Wiki in that case, though.

Comment: This shouldn't need stating, because it's already a copyright violation and liable to flagging for deletion due to non-compliance with the terms of service.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Agreed; however, I have seen just such an answer occur in the past week, so it cannot hurt to hammer home the point in more than one way.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen In that case, I agree the thing to do is mark it as a CW *and* link to the original source with a mention of the author. But even so, in the spirit of the site, I would hope to see at least a "Here's my best attempt at golfing this answer, but as you can see it just can't be improved."

Comment: This can happen accidentally when two people post near the same time, or when the later poster just doesn't read the existing answers fully. Still shouldn't be allowed, but I feel this is less of a "loophole".

Comment: As long as the answer is marked CW and publishing it under the original license is possible (e.g. SE answers are CC by-sa 3.0, so as long as you mention the author and publish on SE you're in the clear) I don't see any problem with it. Don't forget codegolf is on SE and also a Q&A site, not a gaming site. And if you don't like others 'using' your answers don't publish on SE.

Comment: I once had a guy rip off my answer almost entirely, which made extensive use of little used quirks in C#.  His first answer did not even solve the problem, so he took my logic and made it a loop rather than tail recursive.  Thankfully, mine was still smaller, but it really rubbed me the wrong way.  He even copied my explanation for how it worked, with his own style.  Crazy.

Comment: @PeterTaylor not a violation if it's copied from another SE site, or other appropriately licensed source, with any requisite attribution.

Comment: What if the answer works in another different language (obviously with attribution)

Comment: Does this apply for AI-related answers where the AI-asker doesn't golf the response of the AI?

Comment: Sometimes there exist 2 answer in the same language. And you can use one to improve the other and vice versa, sometimes the best answer is a combination of both. What to do in this case? Which answer should be improved?

Answer (score 138):

### Adding input or rules which weren't explicitly mentioned in the challenge

There was recently a case where an answerer claimed

> Nowhere does it say the program can't (also) ask the user what the [result] is.

Adding additional input or new rules, because they haven't been explicitly forbidden, can considerably simplify the challenge or make it trivial. That's certainly not in the spirit of any challenge.

Comment: Do you have a link to this, or was it deleted?

Comment: @PeterTaylor http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32725/8478

Comment: I think this is a bit too broad and certainly curtails any out of the box thinking which may actually be amusing or creative. I do imagine the issue you want to tackle to get annoying, but I'm inclined to think that if a question has specific loopholes that this particular meta has not covered, it is either the fault of the question or the loophole should be added here in it's specific form.

Comment: @jaybz Feel free to reword it to make it a bit more precise. I just thought if I'd write "taking the result as an additional input" it would be *too* narrow. "Taking more input then specified"?

Comment: @MartinBüttner I had a previous reply but I deleted it because I just realized something. I believe [Outsourcing the real answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1085/29081) and
[Fetching the desired output from an external source](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1062/29081) essentially covers that particular case and any similar cases.

Comment: @jaybz I feel like someone said that before (and must have deleted the comment). Basically, while those two have quite generic titles which might cover this case, their descriptions seem to aim very specifically at downloading things from the web - one the answer, the other the program that solves the problem. That's why I added my answer in the first place.

Comment: @MartinBüttner In that case one of those two needs to be a bit broader than they already are. Obviously though, care needs to be taken not to make the loophole descriptions too broad and while I initially didn't want to combine those two for that reason, your recommendation and link convinced me otherwise. They're not even funny the first time.

Comment: Reminds me of [this xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/1552/).

Answer (score 122):

## Zero-length quines

Considering an empty program a quine was original in the [1994 IOCCC](http://www0.us.ioccc.org/1994/smr.hint).

Over two decades later, if you can answer a question with an empty program and that question is scored by length (e.g., [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)) and is tagged as [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine), [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout) or [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source), just notify the OP.

Comment: I mean *technically*, it *is* a quine, since the source is nothing and it outputs nothing

Comment: @TrojanByAccident [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)): a non-empty computer program which takes no input and produces a copy of its own source code as its only output

Comment: In stack based languages without other output, does stack content count as output? In that case in RPL you can get a 1-character quine, like 7, which pushes number 7 onto the stack. Maybe the way to counter it we would want the stack to contain the program listing in a string, so 7 wouldn't count as it would produce 7 rather than "7".

Comment: @Heimdall [Improper quines](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10033/12012) is its own loophole.

Comment: your link is dead

Answer (score 109):

## Using a different name for something that's prohibited

The title is not very clear, I know, but this is what it means: if a specific function is prohibited, someone can use a language where another term than "function" is used (for example "subroutine"), and then that user can claim that their submission is valid because they aren't using a function but a subroutine.

Comment: Seems to be the same as this one: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1077/18865

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg It looks quite different to me. That one is about using functions with different names (for example, using `add` if `+` is forbidden). This one is about, for example, using a specific subroutine (if it's called like that in your language) if the equivalent function is forbidden (for example, using the "subroutine" `add` in your language if the function `add` is forbidden).

Comment: "subroutine"/"function" or "add"/"+", it's all about using the same functionality with another name. Looks very related.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly related. But not really the same. Anyway, it does not hurt having this loophole in another answer.

Comment: This would seem to apply only to a "Do X without Y" question, which is normally a sign of a bad question.

Comment: @ProgramFOX But it's certainly ironic.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 If my memory got it right (it's been almost 5 years since I added this loophole after all), I had seen at least one non-ironic usage of this. Or I missed the irony. Who knows...

Answer (score 94):

## Using a non-free language on a Cops and Robbers challenge

Most (currently all) cops and robbers challenges consist of two parts:

A cop submission, where a user posts some secret property of a program, such as its output, a scrambled version of the code, etc.

Then, other users, the robbers, try to deduce the original program, or another program with the same properties.

An important implicit condition of such a challenge is that it is possible for the robbers to try out many variants of the code to find the true solution. While a cop submission where this is impossible would ostensibly do well, it is not in the spirit of the challenge, and is in fact a loophole.

Therefore, pay-for-use languages are banned from competition in CnR challenges as a loophole.

Some popular languages which are thus banned are:

- Matlab
- STATA

However, [**non-free languages may still be submitted as non-competitive entries**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11726/8478) so as not to exclude potentially interesting cops from being posted altogether. If these are cracked, the crack should also be marked as non-competitive.

Comment: You forgot Mathematica. ;) What about paid-for languages with free trials though?

Comment: And what about Matlab and Octave?

Comment: @MartinBüttner If the free trial can expire, and block a user from using that language afterwards, it's still no good.

Comment: @BetaDecay Octave is fine. Matlab isn't

Comment: I think this warrants a separate meta discussion to decide what is *free enough* for a CnR. For example, is it enough if there is a free *online* interpreter, or if there is a free interpreter that works only with a particular OS?

Comment: Such as AppleScript.

Comment: Mathematica is so popular on this site. TinyMUSH, although free, seemed much worse than that...

Comment: TI-BASIC for the TI-84+ can be emulated easily, but it's technically illegal to do unless you own a calculator. I don't know where that would fall.

Comment: Are there any platform-specific languages?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Well most assembly languages, for instance

Comment: @AlexA. started a discussion about the free-ness [here.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7822/what-constitutes-a-free-language-for-cops-and-robbers)

Comment: Note: Mathematica can now be used freely online.

Comment: We might want to have some rules for this in normal code-golf as well, or else: "My solution to this insanely hard code-golf challenge is the empty program in this language I invented. Trust me, it works. You can verify for yourself by buying the interpreter for $1,000,000."

Comment: @isaacg I think Beta Decay meant that matlab code can be (mostly?) checked with free octave, as they have compatible syntax.

Comment: How "official" does a free method of language access have to be? I imagine you could claim that some pay-to-use langs are free because you can keep making new email addresses for the free trial to use the language forever.

Comment: @lirtosiast What are they gonna do? Arrest me? Make me pick up trash?

Answer (score 93):

### Identical functions with different names

For example, if `+` is forbidden, using

```
num3 = num1.add(num2)
```

or

```
num3 = num1
num3 += num2
```

or

```
num1++
```

or (GolfScript)

```
)
```

etc.

Comment: This is usually semantics. When posting restrictions you have to specify that the restriction applies to all functions and not just that specific one. After that all posts that try to circumvent this can be downvoted/flagged as not an answer

Comment: I see a big difference between addition and increment. Unless you would interpret "`*` is forbidden" as banning `+`, I don't think you should interpret "`+` is forbidden" as banning `++`.

Comment: For `+` and `add` I am on your side. Than again if `/` is forbidden, I would not assume `%` (modulus) is forbidden (and for the same reason I would allow `++` when only `+` is explicitly disallowed).

Answer (score 90):

## Using prior knowledge to circumvent other loopholes

In particular, *gaining an unfair advantage* by inventing new languages for future challenges that are being sandboxed, discussed in chat, are your own, etc.

For example, creating a language that solves a task specified in a sandboxed post with a one-character built-in (or even a zero-byte solution) should be forbidden for [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges.

Likewise, publishing an interpreter [MetaGolfscript-X](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MetaGolfScript) just in time for a challenge should not be allowed.

This does not cover cases such as the creation of [???](http://esolangs.org/wiki/%3F%3F%3F) for [The Programming Language Quiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54807), since there is no advantage in using this particular language for the challenge.

Comment: Does this mean that if you write a language to golf easily, you can't use for challanges?

Comment: @Lucas Inventing your own golfing language is perfectly fine, but you cannot incorporate a one-character built-in for something that is already in the sandbox. That's a) unfair and b) boring.

Comment: Just use first sandbox post date as acceptable language deadline instead of actual question post date.

Comment: @Vi. That's not always the right call. This issue came up because ??? was created for The Programming Language Quiz, which was discussed heavily in chat. Conversely, some challenges are sandboxed for *years* before they get posted.

Comment: @Dinnis, Then maybe allow using languages created even after the challenge officially started provided they are developed **independently** of the challenge participant?

Comment: I think `Using prior knowledge to circumvent ...` may be genuinely intertesting if the method and style is innovative, not just boring re-application of prior hack. Prior art => forbidden loophole; no prior art => good answer (although maybe a non-competing entry). Like "best abuse of rules" in IOCCC.

Answer (score 84):

## Using [MetaGolfScript](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MetaGolfScript)

MetaGolfScript is a family of programming languages. For example, the empty program in MetaGolfScript-209180605381204854470575573749277224 prints "Hello, World!".

It is similar to using extra command line arguments, where they should also count as characters. And using the standard interpreter is likely [using the program name to store data](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1072/25180), except it's the interpreter's name. But someone can build a website with <strike>a fake directory</strike> a directory compressed by a special purpose compression algorithm like all our Kolmogorov complexity challenges, of all MetaGolfScript languages, each with an interpreter can run independently with its filename. They can also use generated descriptions and random code obfuscations to make languages not similar to each other, and it will be hard to say it's still an argument or configuration somewhere.

Comment: Isn't this covered by "languages must have an interpreter before challenge was posted"? Or ["made up languages"](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1071/14215) more specifically?

Comment: @Geobits Someone can make interpreters for MetaGolfScript before those challenges posted. At least they can be appeared to exist on the internet.

Comment: I guess, but that's just plain "lying" or "cheating", not a loophole. Even so, I'd suspect a torrent of downvotes on any such answer to speak for itself.

Comment: Well, I think I'll delete this after a few days.

Comment: I agree that this is obvious and shouldn't need to be a loophole. However, we've recently seen this yet again, so it is clear that we really do need a place to state the obvious and point people to.

Comment: I think this is covered by the interpreter needing to predate the challenge. A *generic* MetaGolfScript interpreter would need command-line arguments to tell it what variation of the language you wanted, and you'd have to pay for those; that's fair. An interpreter for a specific instance of the language (i.e. one specific program) predating the challenge would have nothing to do with MetaGolfScript itself; it'd be more logically akin to the Hello, World program in Stuck.

Comment: @ais523 You could implement a special purpose compression algorithm, and release the interpreters in that format.

Comment: I think it's ok as long as it works as with [using the file name etc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1072/11290). The language name part `209180605381204854470575573749277224` should be included in the byte count making it longer than eg GS version.

Comment: I think this should be extended to include the `perl -nF/(?{s-.*(??{!($&=~y&R&&c==$&=~y&L&&c&&$&=~y&U&&c==$&=~y&D&&c)})--g;print})(*COMMIT)/` language family, now that we consider all of these as different languages as well (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205249)

Answer (score 81):

### Posting a code snippet instead of a complete answer

> **Note**: There is now a [separate question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/62131) covering this loophole in more detail.

This is a issue mainly for [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) and variants.

Only in very few cases this seriously affects [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest).

The issue is when someone post a function, a method, an instruction or a code-snippet instead of a complete program. And then score their answer based on only what was posted. This gives an unfair advantage over who posted a complete solution.

Here is an example of a complete C Hello World program in 53 bytes:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){printf("Hello World!");}
```

But, the answerer, with the intent to defeat another answer in code-golf, posts this instead, claiming that their answer is 22 bytes:

```c
printf("Hello World!")
```

Comment: Provide an example? I don't see anything wrong with this, as long as the snippet does what is required.

Comment: @Doorknob Ok, done.

Comment: In general this is a case where it's the question at fault: vote to close as unclear any question which doesn't specify whether the code supplied should be a full program, a function, an expression.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, ok, but first, we should put it in a comment and see if the OP fixes this quickly, so no one need to worry with closing and eventual reopen. If he/she takes too long or choose to not handle the issue, it is already commented the exact close reason, and eventual answerers would see the comment too and become aware of the issue. Anyway, there could be people doing this on purpose using some more esoteric languages where most people do not sees the difference between an expression and a complete program, and even the ones that do, do not become aware that it is a cheating answer.

Comment: Could you give a better example, that can be easily outdone with `echo Hello World!` in bash unless the question says the answer is required in C

Comment: Well, `printf("Hello World!")` is obviously nonsense, but `main(){printf("Hello World!");}` compiles with GCC.

Comment: Probably alone in this, but to me it sounds perfectly fine to leave the template-y stuff out. It in no way subtracts from the originality needed to write a short answer, but it does allow a lot more languages to compete in codegolf. True, it would be good to describe per language what one considers default stuff, but I doubt there would be a lot of discussion about it.

Comment: There is a more recent meta post for this specific topic [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet).

Comment: **This should include Java answers where the answerer posts a function/method/subroutine/whatever outside of a `class`/`interface`/`enum`.**

Comment: @dorukayhan EXACTLY - This was precisely what I was thinking for when I originally posted this a few years ago.

Comment: @Doorknob This Way Java will never suck for code golfing

Answer (score 68):

## Suicidal entries to King-of-the-Hill challenges.

[EmoWolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25347/survival-game-create-your-wolf/25357#25357) was funny the first time, but [it's getting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/34833/save-the-last-bullet-for-yourself/34856#34856) [out of hand](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35329/8478).

While some not-too-serious answers are often necessary to kickstart a [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) challenge, purely suicidal answers put in little effort and tend to get more upvotes than serious entries, simply because they're "funny".

I'm not suggesting that other answers that are for jokes shouldn't be allowed, but this specific kind that is not even trying to do anything. Submissions should at least *play* the game, even if badly or in a funny way.

Comment: I'd prefer if this loophole was a bit more closely cut to purely suicidal submissions. I find that joke submissions in general are very important to get many KotHs going. For instance, if people had only ever posted serious submissions to RPSLV, there would have been no game, since nothing can beat a uniformly random strategy with anything but luck. Furthermore, KotHs need many submissions to be fun, and a bunch of less serious submissions in the beginning help a lot to explore the strategy space and gather some popularity.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I agree. That's what I tried to say in the last paragraph. I guess I failed.

Comment: That last sentence does point in this direction, but I'm sure if it gets more upvotes as it stands it will be used in the future to justify downvotes for any sort of non-competitive KotH submission. I'll give rephrasing it a go later. Feel free to rollback or improve that any time.

Comment: Out of hand? [You don't say?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35472/14215)

Comment: In AlienWar (http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32782/survival-game-alienwar/), I'm somewhat worried about solutions that only set the ability points and implement the methods trivially, like the Manager and Banana Peel. Well, some KotH games are designed to let trivial implementations thrive.

Comment: Even purely suicidal submissions could still be a viable strategy, depending on the contest. If it works, and is allowed by the rules (especially when there's an explicit suicide action!), this really isn't much of a loophole.

Comment: Surely the solution is to not specifically allow a 'suicide' command in the game?

Comment: Suicidal entries to [tag:king-of-the-hill] challenges are not serious cotnenders.

Answer (score 61):

## Creating a new compiler for a language after a challenge was posted

There is some debate arising from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55351/34718). He created his own compiler for the C programming language that extends the language specifications. It seems pretty obvious that this will be declared a loophole, to me at least, but I'm posting this for the record.

Comment: I’d even go so far as to say that extending the language makes it a new and different language, and is therefore a special case of [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1071/668)

Comment: @Timwi So would I, but the user in the linked answer wouldn't accept that fact.

Comment: I would put it differently: answers may only make use of a language _as it existed_ at the time the challenge was posted. If it depends on features added after the challenge was posted, it is invalid. But if you can prove your modification to the language has been published online before the challenge was posted, I don't consider this a problem.

Comment: @user2428118 That's already a rule and is mandated. It's not a loophole.

Comment: As the user referred to in this question, I still don't believe that this is a special case of existing loopholes.  For example, a user could submit an empty source file written in the language Undefined (https://esolangs.org/wiki/Undefined) as a solution to any question, after requiring that the program be compiled with <new compiler that compiles empty source to xxx program>.  That's making use of the language Undefined as it has always existed.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 The goal in golfing is ***not*** to "get around" loopholes, which is exactly what you were trying to do. You're being intentionally dishonest in how you were answering. Languages are defined by their *implementation*, and the *compiler* is part of the implementation. Your all-new compiler did not exist at the time the question was posted. It is also a forbidden loophole now, simply because it has 33 upvotes establishing meta consensus.

Comment: @mbomb007 I was one of the 33 people who voted for this, and I take issue with your statement that I was intentionally dishonest.  I was always completely open about how my solution worked and that the compiler did not exist before the question was posted.  And I think you'll have a hard time backing up your statement that 'languages are defined by their implementation', particularly for a language like C, for which there are numerous official standards available.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 It's meta consensus that **on this site** we define a language by its implementation. Every implementation is considered unique. "We", meaning, all of us.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 And you have to realize, we all disagree with you. Your comments in the discussion on your answer that was invalidated show that you still don't get it, and are trying to rationalize your usage of something we determined to be forbidden.

Comment: @mbomb007 A word of advice - when you're trying to convince someone of a point of view, it's actually counterproductive to adopt an attitude that they're being "intentionally dishonest", that they "won't accept" things and that they "don't get it", and to adopt a combative and offensive stance when talking to them.  I don't know where all this anger is coming from when I have *always* tried to be reasonable.  I have, by and large, agreed with the community and accepted their point of view, mainly thanks to other users who have been more polite to me.

Comment: Thanks anyway for pointing out the meta consensus on how a language is defined on this site - I'm not sure how I missed that, but now I've done a quick search I've found some posts about it.  So I apologise for calling that into doubt earlier; I genuinely didn't realize that that was the official consensus and thought that it was just an opinion held by some users on this site.

Comment: My anger is only now, because you're bumping this and it's more than a year old, and you still didn't get it, apparently.

Comment: Your post leaves a loophole itself: building a _transpiler_ is still possible!

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms We don't allow languages to be posted unless they have an interpreter. A transpiler wouldn't be enough to allow an answer to be posted.

Comment: @mbomb007 Just a joke. I knew about the interpreter-only rule already.

Comment: Just require that the compiler's characters be counted. Problem solved.

Answer (score 61):

## Abusing native number types to trivialize a problem

It is common practice to restrict challenges to cases where input, output and/or intermediate values of the algorithm of choice fit into the language's native number type. At least for input and output, this is generally assumed even if not stated in the challenge specification.

There are at least two ways to abuse this:

1. Using a language like [Boolfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Boolfuck) which only has a 1-bit integer type.

   With one bit of input and one bit of output, there are only four different Boolfuck programs that can solve *all* challenges.

   So far, at least two answers have done this:

   - [Print the N-bonacci sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70532)
   - [Print the amount of ones in a binary number without using bitwise operators](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52778)
2. Deliberately exceeding the precision limit.

   I don't know if this has been done before, but one could start by computing [**A(4, y)**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AckermannFunction.html) for input **y** (a 19,728 digit integer for **y = 2**), and then do anything that works for inputs **1** and **0**.

As a rule of thumb, I'd say an answer *abuses* the native number type if the code would require non-trivial modifications for larger number type.

Examples:

- Implementing bit rotations as

  ```
  (x << n) | (x >> (32 - n))
  ```

  for 32-bit integers is *allowed*; only the `32` has to be changed to make it work for, e.g., 64-bit integers.
- Hardcoding a list of the prime numbers below 128 is *not allowed* in a challenge that involves primality testing, even if the language of choice only supports signed 8-bit integers.

Comment: I'd say instead that the flaw is in the challenge, and the default should be that the *algorithm* should work for all ℕ when precision/range limits are disregarded.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem, but a solution. Good on those users for thinking outside the box.

Comment: @tuskiomi The first time it was used was clever, but this trick could be applied to pretty much all challenges that do not state in what range the submissions must work.

Comment: @Dennis I'd say, if the input doesn't match the challenge, it isn't an appropriate answer. It's arbitrary at this point that ints are 32 bit, doubles 64, floats 32, shorts 16, bools 1/8, and Strings are infinite.

Comment: I know it's years since this was posted but I had a thought. "Hardcoding a list of the prime numbers below 128 is not allowed" -- what about including the single 128-bit value 0x800228A20208828828208A20A08A28AC or binary `10000000000000100010100010100010000000100000100010000010100010000010100000100000100010100010000010100000100010100010100010101100` which is a bitmap of the primes from zero to 127?

Comment: @RossPresser That's still hardcoding. The format doesn't matter.

Comment: For challenges that don't specify input ranges, this can go the other way: demanding a function works with 128 bits, 256 bits, etc. can be unreasonable for languages that only offer native support for 32 bit types. I think it's reasonable to accept 32 bit as a default sized input.

Comment: @qwr Are you talking about the algorithm or the implementation? I don't think a submission in a "32-bit language" should have to support 64-bit input, but I *do* think the underlying algorithm should.

Comment: I think the point is not abusing the fact that given limits of the language the set of inputs is finite, and the solution can be hardcoded. It is a particular case of the "do not hard-code" rule https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1063/25245

Answer (score 60):

## Optimising for the given test cases

This applies to [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)s and things like [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), where you write some code that is measured by a criterion like runtime or size of your output (e.g. in compression challenges). These often employ an obviously finite set of test cases, because you have to measure the metric *somehow*.

It's not in the spirit of such challenges if an answer optimises exclusively for those test cases (e.g. by hardcoding them, which would usually allow you to compress them to a single byte or execute in milliseconds), but performing much worse for general/random input.

For variable-sized input there is no way around test cases (one can use some sort of big-O class for scoring, but those tend to not be accurate enough to distinguish submissions and they require proofs instead of just running the code), so the code of conduct should be that the algorithm is such that the test cases are actually representative for the implementation's performance.

This also means, that if you optimise your algorithm to perform well on the *majority* of cases (and worse on a handful of edge cases) and the test cases happen to be picked from that majority, that's perfectly fine. However, optimising for a *minority* of cases which include one or more of the test cases is not.

Comment: +1, but also I think it would be useful guidance for question setters to either score on the worst-case input, or take such a wide variety of input that it's impossible to optimise. This is because it's hard to see from an answer whether it's been optimised for the test cases or 'happens' to give a good answer for a small amount of test input data.

Comment: @abligh Yes, larger sets test cases help mitigate that, but even those can be hardcoded. And scoring by worst-case input only really works for fixed-size problems.

Comment: With respect to: "but performing very badly for general input", the example that inspired trying to close this loophole permits performing optimally on _all_ cases, yet still permit optimizing for the test cases.  In that example, the result is effectively an integer between 0 and 6,670,903,752,021,072,936,959.  It is easy to map _n_ test cases to 0.._n_, resulting in compression to a single character (or less) for those cases, while having exactly zero impact on the average performance.  So you may want to remove that condition to closing the loophole.

Comment: @MarkAdler how about now?

Comment: By the way, detecting an optimization for the minority of cases may be extremely subtle.  For example, simple choices in the ordering of what is looked at or the numbering of symbols could be optimized to improve performance on the test cases.  Again having no impact on the average performance.  This is fine loophole to try to close, but be prepared for ambiguity and arguments about whether it applies or not.

Comment: I guess that's better.

Answer (score 53):

### Generating all possible functions/programs to solve a challenge

In [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9031/unnamed-functions-in-code-golf), isaacg pointed out that, under current consensus, the following Python code (edited to fix a mistake) could possibly be viewed as valid:

```
for i, code in enumerate(all_possible_strings):
    try: exec("func" + str(i) + "=" + code)
    except: pass
```

Given enough time, the desired function will eventually be generated and assigned to `func<some large number>`, which could then be called with the desired arguments and would return the desired result.

Though we do not forbid brute-forcing, solutions of this sort are clearly exploitative in the same vein as MetaGolfScript, and we certainly do not want this solution on every challenge where functions are allowed.

Comment: Can you explain for non-pythonians what this snippet exactly does?

Comment: @flawr For every possible string (enumerated with some running index `i`), it defines a function `func<i>` whose body is that string. Some of those will solve the problem at hand, and given any (ungolfed) solution to the problem it's even quite easy to reverse the process to figure out which number that is, so you could just submit that and then say "the function is named `func102947812904`".

Comment: But in tat case function to enumerate strings should be included. Also, if we force to count length of function name in such case, it will be longer then function body itself.

Comment: @Qwertiy The name wouldn't be included in the byte count, because it's trying them *all*. He's telling you so that the viewer knows *which* string was the one that runs. The name doesn't occur in the program's original code at all.

Comment: @mbomb007, yes. But we have a rule about additional compilation keys - they are not inside of code, but they do count. So if we force to count name in this case - it'll solve problem with golf but would still allow to make some interesting things.

Comment: Isn't this the Halting problem? What's to guarantee that you get to a solution in an infinite search space?

Comment: @xdhmoore *Given enough time* is the key here - since we usually don't impose time restrictions in code golf, solutions which can take multiple lifetimes of the universe to complete are valid (assuming they don't break any other rules).

Comment: I know that's practically correct, but that doesn't sound right math-wise. Maybe I'm missing something. Maybe math isn't the point :)

Comment: You're going to lose if you use this because the name of the function is longer than the target.

Comment: @xdhmoore You are correct in pointing this out. Once a non-halting program is discovered, the process of generating programs stops. But there is a well-known workaround: simulate the first function for 1 time step, then the first 2 functions for 2 time steps, the first 3 for 3 time steps, and so on. Now non-halting programs don't impede progress. I believe the technical term is _dovetailing_.

Comment: This program is broken, since as soon as it evaluates "while true: \n&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; pass\n", it infinitely loops and never reaches the end. Point is valid, but I would implement it differently: Have a pool of preemptible coroutines. Each iteration, add a coroutine to the pool corresponding to the evaluation of a string. The iterate over all coroutines. If one does not halt after a second, preempt it and leave it in the pool to continue on where it left off next iteration. This guarantees that all strings eventually get iterated over on an idealized computer.

Comment: @eaglgenes101 The program is the wrong thing to focus on here.

Comment: This is my kind of program...just let it run, and eventually it will create the next big thing

Comment: @eaglgenes101 No. The program merely defines the function. At no point are any of the functions actually run. E.g. https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNQ9OKS0GhPCMzJ1UhpKg01UpBT0@Pq6AoM69EQ8mtNC@5JDM/TwGoNDMvNUVRSfP/fwA

Comment: However, it does kind of need modification. But no really as extreme as the answers seem to imply.

Answer (score 45):

## Changing your username to fit a username dependent challenge

Changing your username or registering a new one to make your score better in username or userID dependent challenges.

Comment: I can't think of a recent challenge that required this; could you link to one where having a specific username would give you an advantage?

Comment: @M.I.Wright Username: [Output your username without using any of the characters in your username! \[duplicate\]](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51252/output-your-username-without-using-any-of-the-characters-in-your-username) UserID: [Red vs. Blue - Pixel Team Battlebots](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48353/red-vs-blue-pixel-team-battlebots)

Comment: I think the problem then would be in the question itself rather than the answer, since it is giving an unfair advantage for some people. I think no post should be dependant on the username/id

Comment: Some users are just fond of changing their names; it would restrict our freedom. A really good question relies on the user number, which is rigid. The ones that rely on usernames can be regarded as “take any string you want, just do not forget to throw it on your settings page”. And sometimes you can do very witty things with that!

Comment: my username is 1. <s>`2-1`</s> `3-2`. How did I manage to mess that up?!

Comment: This reminds me of Pokemon Blue Arbitrary Code Execution, because some depend on your trainer ID.

Answer (score 41):

## URL shorteners / shortened URLs

Every once in a while, we get a challenge that requires fetching some data from the internet. While some of them manage to ban URL shorteners in time, other don't. I propose to forbid them by default because of the following reasons.

1. URL shorteners that were created after the challenge was posted are akin to adding a feature to the interpreter after the challenge was posted, and there's usually no easy way to determine when a shortened URL was created. They also outsource the "real" URL, which is more or less a violation of [this loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1085/12012). Last but not least, it's oftentimes not possible to determine whether a given URL existed before the challenge was posted.
2. Using a non-canonical URL is not only a bit unimaginative and rather unrelated to programming, the same URL can be used in pretty much *all* answers. Every time someone finds a shorter URL, all other posts can be updated to use that URL as well. That's a very tedious and boring way of saving bytes.
3. In some challenges, API queries have to be made. Being able to fit a very complex query – which will make parsing its output easier – in the same amount of bytes as simple one actively harms the challenge; instead of coming up with clever ways to parse the output, the complex query is "golfed" down using a URL shortener.

URL shorteners are rather easy to identify. That leaves non-canonical domain names.

I propose counting all URLs on domains as shortened (and therefore forbidden) if the domain name isn't owned by the same individual/company as the canonical one. Thus, e.g., if the task at hand involves querying https://api.stackexchange.com, only URLs that belong to Stack Exchange, Inc. may be used in the challenge.

Comment: Why, I don't really agree. The principle of code-golf is that you want to shorten everything - why not the URL? You should let OP decide for this, in place of saying it is a standard loophole. Actually, for every challenge using data from internet, the question 'can I shorten URL' is asked, and every answerer is at last using a bit.ly link.

Comment: @V.Courtois The OP can still decide; this is just the default.

Comment: I disagree with the final paragraph. I think it can be fun to get a long url by other means than to store it directly in the source code, and I think we should ban url shortening services specifically. That is information that you have stored somewhere else, and you may not do that, much in the same way that you may not create a language specifically to solve a question.

Comment: I think the correct solution is to count the database entry on the URL shortener as part of the solution for the byte count.  If custom code on the URL shortener is involved, then it all counts too.

Comment: That last clause seems to have some pretty big loopholes, like if the company in question happens to operate a public URL shortener, then you can do whatever you want with it? I think the main consideration here is that if you're using a URL shortener, you're essentially storing code/data somewhere, and therefore you should count that data in your solution.

Comment: @V.Courtois shortening the url is allowed, so long as the full mechnism used to retrieve the full-sized URL in part of the submission.  this rule is about using code and resources maintained by external services as part of your answer.

Answer (score 38):

## When consistent and distinct values are asked as input, you cannot input complete or partial functions

When I create a challenge and ask for a `boolean` or two 'consistent and distinct values' I mean it in the sense of a truthy and falsey value. Usually I leave the choice to the ones doing the challenge, since I don't care whether it's `true/false`, `1/0`, `"yes"/"no"`, etc.

I know just asking for a [truthy/falsey value](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/52210) specifically in the challenges is also an option, but since `1/0` isn't considered truthy/falsey in for example Java or .NET C# and I still don't mind if they are used, this default loop hole would be relevant.

Since it isn't part of this default loopholes page yet, there have been answers in the past which input partial or complete functions, if the challenge rules allow this loophole. [This JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141025/52210) for example, takes the inputs as `'/\n|-DI>-/---< '` for left, `'/\n|-DI<-\\---> '` for right. In the challenge description it states:

> the other being one of two distinct, consistent values of your choice (`1 / 0`, `l / r`, `left / right`, etc.)
> ...
> [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

Although original, and it does comply with the challenge description above, I think it would be wise to prevent these kind of partial or complete functions as input in the future. What would prevent someone from having the fictional program `run param` where the `param` is a complete program when a truthy value is asked, or a different complete program when a falsey value is asked? Also sharply [mentioned by *@darrylyeo* as comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/140943/ascii-airplane-banner/141025#comment345583_140943) on that same challenge:

> JavaScript, 4 bytes: `eval` - Input a program that generates a left-facing plane for left, and a program that generates a right-facing plane for right.

[Related: Using the program name to store data without counting those bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1072/52210)
In this related loophole the file-name is counted towards the byte-count. But I don't think adding the two values to the byte-count is a good idea either, otherwise the `1/0`, `true/false` should also be counted. Where do we draw the line of which inputs should be counted towards the byte-count, and which shouldn't? So just preventing these kind of inputs as standard loophole would be better in my opinion.

Comment: Where will you draw the line between valid and invalid here? I can't think of a borderline case right now, but I think there might be some grey area here and we need to be able to make a definitive objective decision about it.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I agree. Been thinking the same thing just yet. I remember seeing some answers with parameters like `A/null`, using the `A` for something in the code if present, which is part of the grey area you're talking about. So I'm also not sure how to consistent and definitively define it. Maybe never allowing string/text inputs, but I can imagine there are some programming languages out there without boolean nor number inputs and only have string parameter options. So yes, I definitely agree it should be specified a lot better, but I'm not sure how (yet).

Comment: I consider this is most similar to [extra inputs](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1789/71434); specifically it's "hiding" extra inputted information inside an input which IS part of the challenge specification. I'm not certain of a good way to objectively distinguish when that happens though.

Comment: One possible rigorous definition of falling into this loophole is this: Suppose that the program expects foo as an input for the program, and take bar to be an arbitrary alternate input that we want the program to accept instead of foo. If patching the program to accept bar instead of foo would entail translating bar into foo or otherwise incorporating a portion of foo into the program, it falls under this loophole. (I have a sneaking suspicion that this doesn't work quite right for data typing-based inputs, but that's what other heads are for, right?)

Comment: Can I do this but add the byte count of input function?

Comment: While I agree with the intent of this post, the wording needs work. `1`, `0`, `l`, and `r` *are* complete functions in Jelly.

Comment: @Dennis Hmm.. good point. But what would be a good alternative wording. Feel free to edit it as you see fit, btw; it's a community wiki for a reason.

Answer (score 35):

## Outputting an expression instead of a number

For example, outputting `3*3` instead of `9`, or outputting `7/4` instead of `1.75`.

Unless the challenge explicitly allows expression output, the output should be in a number format where a number is requested.

As the comments point out that what counts as a number format is hard to define, there's a separate meta discussion [Which number formats are acceptable in output?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9263/which-number-formats-are-acceptable-in-output)

Comment: This is common sense. It shouldn't even *need* to be written down. +1.

Comment: It never occurred to me to write it down until someone asked if they could use it, and I realised I didn't have a place to point to in order to say no...

Comment: I think this is a bit fuzzy. Yes, you shouldn't be allowed to output a expression, but some things (Like `2/3` vs. `0.6666`) should be allowed IMO.

Comment: Perhaps we need a new meta post to cover which number formats are acceptable by default (for things like .1 instead of 0.1 and scientific notation and rationals and symbolic constants).

Comment: I posted a [more detailed meta discussion](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9263/which-number-formats-are-acceptable-in-output)

Comment: I think this would kill creativity. If it is asked to output `14` and  your programme prints `2*7` or `2×7` or `2·7`, normally a sane person would write a code that evaluates to 14 because printing an expression is seldom easier. There are a bunch of hugely upvoted answers that, for example, print ASCII art instead of numbers, which is even more creative. And throw a rock at me if 7·2≠14.

Comment: @AndreïKostyrka In Bases 8, 9, B-D and F-`\inf` it isn't... :-)

Comment: It's hard to define this clearly. Is 1e2 an expression or a number? Is 1e9? Is 1.43e20? 1.43e22? (FWIW, Javascript expands 1.43e20 but ouputs 1.43e22 as is...)

Comment: @SteveBennett yes this topic proved to be worth its own separate meta discussion (see my previous comment), and there are a variety of answers there covering more detail. Feel free to add another answer each time something turns up that is not covered.

Answer (score 35):

### Using a language's lack of features to trivialize a challenge

This is in the same vein as [this other loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8245/45941).

Consider [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/106704/45941). Using a language that cannot access an Internet connection would be a violation of this loophole - it could simply output a falsey output all the time, because it would never be able to access the Internet.

Comment: Challenge: "Check if this device is connected to the internet". If your language cannot determine that, it's the wrong tool for the job and therefore an invalid submission. All you can say fir sure is that _your program_ is not connected to the internet, but it says nothing about the device as a whole.

Answer (score 33):

### Generating a random stream of output when a specific output is required

For example, if a challenge requires you to output `4`, you can't output an infinite stream of random digits, and say "4 is in there somewhere!" You must output `4`, and no other number.

This is similar to [this other loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9034/45941).

Comment: I would not consider this as a loophole. This just does not meet the specifications of the corresponding challenge and is therefore invalid. Why do you want to explicitly add this as a *loophole*?

Comment: +1, but it's essentially covered by http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8379/8478 if you consider the RNG's seed as part of the program's input.

Comment: @MartinEnder Good point, I didn't think about that meta post. I don't think it hurts to have it explicitly stated here as well as on that post.

Comment: @Mego I think what is allowed or isn't should always be clear from the challenge itself. Can you provide an example where we *need* this loophole rule? (Where this is not alredy clear from the challenge itself?) Otherwise I think this is a tautology, which does not make any sense adding here. We could write a ton of others such as *"loophole: if the output must be true you cannot output false"* The challenge requiring you to output 4 does exactly *imply* that you cannot output any other number.

Comment: @flawr [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/83873/theoretically-output-grahams-number), before I added the word "deterministically".

Comment: If you do not add *deterministically* your challenge really asks for the *infinite monkeys* solutions, which would be perfectly fine under these challenge rules. I can imagine that the loophole as it is now would restrain certain solutions for code-challenges or popularity-contests. I suggest rephrasing it, as it does not really catch the problem of LeakyNun's challenge. My suggestions: *"Generating a random sream of output when specific output is required"* with *"For example, if a challenge requires you to output 4, you cannot output and infinite stream of random digits."*.

Comment: @flawr I agree with your improved wording and have made the edit.

Comment: I still think that if the challenge requires you to output `4` and you output something like `8 7 1 2 4 3 5 6` you simply don't meet the specs

Comment: @LeakyNun, if this is really a problem with that question (and I agree with those who are saying that it isn't) then adding the word "*deterministically*" doesn't fix anything. If finding the desired output somewhere in the middle of a stream of junk meets spec then the stream can be generated deterministically for *fewer* characters than required to generate it randomly.

Comment: @LuisMendo Right, this is all in all quite similar to [this loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9034/24877), so they could probably be merged?

Comment: @flawr I'd say it's not even a loophole, it's an answer that doesn't meet the specs

Comment: @LuisMendo I wouldn't agree with that, since you could argue that the program has a chance to get the correct result (and not "chance" as in "clearly invalid program produces correct output because cosmic rays cause a bit to be flipped at the right time"). Often there is a very reasonable likelihood of getting the right output by chance, so you'll see a lot of programs on the Anarchy Golf server using randomness, although usually to select a canned output (which AFAIK is already a loophole here).

Comment: I think this loophole description is too narrow. I suspect you also want something like `1.` to be an invalid entry. It's a program which deterministically prints Graham's number in unary. It's followed by additional digits, but it's not simply a case of "Graham's number is in there somewhere": Graham's number appears right at the start, with nothing in between, and extra output at the end is generally considered to be valid. (Or should I post that as an answer? (: )

Comment: @hvd I believe that is already covered by another loophole. I'd drop a link, but navigating this post on mobile is a nightmare. Look for "abusing number systems".

Comment: @Mego That doesn't appear anywhere on either of the two pages of answers here, and I cannot find that using Google either. Could it be a answer somewhere that has since been deleted? Or are you mixing it with "Abusing native number types to trivialize a problem"? That doesn't cover my idea.

Comment: I don't think the randomness is important here. The important part is whether is is allowed to output more than the expected output or not.

Answer (score 32):

## Improper quines

We've reached consensus on what counts as a [proper quine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4877/12012) over a year ago, yet the occasional "quine" that consists of nothing more than literals and/or NOPs still comes up.

While these answers used to be tolerated (and, on occasions, applauded) unless the challenge specifically asked for a *proper* quine, the community has recently started to downvote and/or delete improper quines even if the challenge didn't explicitly disallow them.

This course of action is a sane default; almost all quine-related challenges are rendered trivial if the program `1` is deemed quine enough for a submission. To back these actions with community consensus, I therefore propose the following.

> If the challenge asks for quines and its spec doesn't explicitly allow improper quines, all submissions have to be *proper* quines.
>
> If the challenge mentions quines and/or is tagged with [quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quine), a program that would count as an improper quine (if its output matched its source code) is likewise disallowed.

Comment: what is an improper quine, *de facto*?

Comment: @V.Courtois `cat $0` in Bash or `This is a quine.` is PHP.

Answer (score 24):

## Output shall be non-trivial (e. g. not empty)

Mainly targeting [code-challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenges) where the score is determined by the output. This results in very boring, but valid, answers which tend to get upvoted especially on pop-cons with no other answers.

---

An example: if the goal was to output the Mona Lisa as close as possible.
Outputting a blank image should be considered a loophole.

---

Another Example: In a  [test-battery](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-battery) [such as this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69920/40695) where score is determined by the most correct output. Always outputting false and claiming a score of `0` should count as a loophole.

Comment: This is already forbidden by our rules. Answers must make a serious attempt at competing.

Comment: Already mentioned in [the help center](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I didn't think the "serious attempts" fully covered it because many of these types of answers can be considered "serious" attempts and still violate this loophole. I've reworded

Comment: Your edits so far only describe what is already forbidden by the serious attempt rule.

Comment: I think that if the empty output actually gives a good score, then it should not be considered a loophole. If it was actually a serious attempt (which means that it would actually give a good score), then that means that it's a flaw in the challenge, not the answer

Answer (score 22):

## Using an inconsistent I/O format to encode information

For example, for a hypothetical challenge where the output could only ever be two or eleven, submitting the python program

```
lambda x:print"11"
```

and claiming that it outputs in unary for certain inputs and in decimal for other inputs should not be allowed, even though outputting in either of these bases [is usually allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5344).

Likewise, for a [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) challenge, submitting the python function

```
lambda i:type(i)is str
```

and claiming it takes input as a singleton list for inputs that match the challenge's criteria and as a string otherwise shouldn't be allowed, even though taking input as a singleton list [is usually allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11884).

Comment: Is this an issue which has actually come up, or a pre-emptive strike against a hypothetical answer?

Comment: It hasn't been a problem as far as I know, but I figured it might be best to have it written down either way. Maybe it would have been better to wait until it actually was a problem, but this feels like the kind of rules lawyering that someone would come up with soon enough and that wouldn't be all that interesting even the first time.

Answer (score 21):

### Outputting Unicode characters in [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) challenges

If a challenge requires an image to be output, outputting a Unicode character instead is not acceptable. In [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) challenges, the output should always be an image.

Comment: Disagree. If you're outputting say HTML+CSS, it seems just as valid to use a Unicode character as to use SVG, CSS or any other method to draw a circle, for instance. Of course, individual challenges can still ban unicode chars if they want.

Comment: @SteveBennett In challenges which say "output an image" (which is all [tag:graphical-output] challenges), an output consisting of one or more Unicode characters is not acceptable because it is not an image (excepting those obvious exceptions where it is a textual encoding of an image).

Comment: Based on what definition of "image"? Is SVG an "image"? Is HTML? What about SVG that contains unicode characters?

Comment: @SteveBennett Now you're just splitting hairs.

Comment: No, I think you are. I'm saying all these things qualify as outputting an image, and you're (implicitly) saying that some of them don't - so I'm asking you where you're drawing that line.

Comment: @SteveBennett Here's a simple (but not perfect) test: if `display` (from the ImageMagick toolkit) can display it, it's an image. If not, then it's not.

Comment: That's a definition of an image *file*.

Comment: Also, from the documentation, a directory of image files would qualify, so...yeah imperfect. :)

Comment: It sounds like you really want to impose some kind of minimum resolution requirement.  Are you trying to rule out programs that generate ascii-art graphics?  Some video players (like mplayer/mpv) have ASCII-art video-output drivers, as well as the usual opengl, vdpau, X11, and so on.  e.g. http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/h/4441.

Comment: Or are you really trying to rule out using just a couple characters, effectively taking major advantage of font glyphs instead of drawing pixels directly or with image-library functions?

Comment: If you can see it, then it’s an image.

Comment: Wouldn’t any Unicode character output also require to specify a font? Otherwise it’s just a byte, it does not say what it looks like. If my default font represents “O” like an “X”, it does not look like a circle any more. SVG and HTML however specify (default) fonts/font families.

Answer (score 21):

## Exactly duplicating another answer

This specifically came up for me in a [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill) contest. In particular, this contest had a random component, so replicating a submission could allow one to win by luck.

In general, duplicate submissions are uninteresting, and do not add anything to any sort of contest, king of the hill, code golf or otherwise.

Importantly, even if the posters came up with the answers separately, duplicate answers should still be banned.

Comment: I don't think this really needs to be stated. It seems like in your challenge the duplicate poster was just unaware of the basic bots you had posted.

Comment: @Chris I'm not thinking of the situation that game up in my contest. I'm thinking of the potential exploit where someone just copy-pastes the leading answer. This is obviously not allowed, and so goes here, on the list of stuff that's obviously not allowed.

Comment: Well, that's [already on here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1080/58834) ;)

Comment: @Chris The implication of that question seems to be that it's about copying a solution from another source, e.g. not stack exchange. But more importantly, I'm saying they should be banned even if they were invented separately, as can happen in KotH challenges.

Comment: The current consensus actually [allows duplicate answers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/56433).

Comment: @Laikoni That answer isn't specific to KotH

Answer (score 21):

### Using cryptographic functions in a cops and robbers challenge

Almost every cops and robbers challenge will have the following requirement:

> Using cryptographic functions such as hashes or PRNGs is disallowed

...and for good reason. A trivial answer such as `if (hash(input) == "[ example_hash ]") return true` is near impossible to crack, yet requires almost no ingenuity on the part of the cop.

Some very specific challenges may not be susceptible to trivial solutions like these, but the default should be to consider hashing functions a loophole. I'm surprised this isn't already here, I think it would save everyone a lot of typing if this was the default policy :D

Comment: Related discussion [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10793/78410) and [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7623/78410).

Comment: "some very specific challenges may not be susceptible": I think relatively few challenges are.

Comment: [Here's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/140793/46076) a challenge that explicitly allows cryptographic functions. Not that it matters, because challenges are allowed to override standard loopholes, but pointing it out anyway. The only problem with it is the large number of invalid answers.

Comment: _mathematically impossible_ – It's not impossible, it's just computationally infeasible.

Comment: @forest Changed it to "near impossible". Thanks!

Comment: What if you implement it yourself?

Comment: @Iamkindofalanguagedev Still invalid. How it's implemented is unobservable and irrelevant to the reasons for why this is annoying

Answer (score 19):

## Storing information in platform specifications

We often allow people to require certain qualities of the machine their answer is run on, (for example Operating System).  However we should disallow requiring the program to be run on a certain specification to store information used for the challenge.

For example the language [Nullary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Nullary) only has zero length programs instead deriving its source from the time since epoch.  Similar languages could be created to exploit things such as monitor/terminal size, screen brightness, volume or even Operating System.

These types of answers should be disallowed.

Comment: I'm not sure about this one. For example, there could be languages where its interpreter only works properly on one operating system.

Comment: @Okx Its not forbidding specifing the platform, only drawing information from the platform to circumvent having to put it in the program.

Comment: What I mean is, that the interpreter could act slightly differently on different operating systems (as, for example, it may not have some operating system specific function) therefore breaking answers. But about *storing* information that, I totally agree.

Comment: I think this would be better rephrased as creating an environment, and it goes together with having the output pre-stored in a file already (unless you actually have an os that has that stuff stored there by default)

Comment: Hmm. There was a Bash answer to the "output any string as long as the program" that ran `arch`, which outputs `i386` on the appropriate hardware. I found that pretty creative - not cheaty at all.

Comment: Nullary is not a programming language as no code can be given to it.

Answer (score 18):

### Sidestepping in a theorem-proving challenge

A theorem-proving challenge is about proving a statement (= constructing a value of the given type) given in a specific host language (designed for theorem proving, most likely Lean or Coq).

One problem with this is that the host language may have various utilities that allow writing a "proof" that is not actually a sound proof of the given statement. This loophole bans any kind of answer that does this, including (but not limited to):

- Using a feature that introduces explicit holes in a proof (in Lean, `sorry`, `axiom`, `admit`)
- Using a feature that allows introducing a value of False (in Lean, `constant`)
- Proving a similar-looking, but not identical statement. e.g. in Lean,

  ```
  local notation a `=` b := true
  theorem X (n : ℕ) :
    ((list.nat.antidiagonal n).map (function.uncurry nat.choose)).sum
    = n.succ.fib := trivial
  ```

  is not considered a valid proof of

  ```
  theorem X (n : ℕ) :
    ((list.nat.antidiagonal n).map (function.uncurry nat.choose)).sum
    = n.succ.fib
  ```

Answer (score 14):

## Features added to a pre-existing language, after the challenge was posted

See [Covfefify a string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123685/covfefify-a-string). This might been solved in 45 bytes using:

```
select covfefify(:a) from dual@datadictionary
```

This isn't the same as these pre-existing loopholes:

- Using a made-up language specifically designed for the challenge: it is not a made-up language; it is a programming language in use.
- Using prior knowledge to circumvent other loopholes: it is not made up.
- Creating a new compiler for a language after a challenge was posted: it is not creating a new compiler, but extending an existing grammar.

None of these covers the scenario where an existing language is extended by a new function.

Comment: It's the same as creating a new compiler. It's not a compiler, but it's still adding a feature after the challenge.

Comment: And was this what you meant? I tried to clarify a bit.

Comment: Hi @Riker, yes, this covers the loophole I think. I now find it impossible to perform fraud using this loophole.

Comment: I would argue that the bytes added or changed in adding a language feature are part of your byte count for the challenge.  While it is unlikely to be small, maybe someone has written a golfing language in a golfing language.

Answer (score 13):

## Exploiting the controller in a King-of-the-Hill challenge

I'm surprised that this wasn't here before, but [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201559/52194) found a loophole to exploit in the KotH problem that should really be sealed off. (The rules of the challenge at time of writing only forbade using code that modifies the controller or the other bots, so the bot in question returned NaN instead knowing that the way it interacts with comparison operations would ensure that it would always be eliminated last.)

Comment: If you find a behaviour in the controller that seems to be against the spirit of the challenge, it is better to report it by commenting on the question rather than post an answer exploiting it.

Comment: Define "exploiting the controller".

Comment: @thedefault. Seems to me like a "know it when you see it" type thing. Taking advantage of what is obviously a bug, changing global variables to mess up other bots, getting forbidden information by tricking the controller, and so on.

Answer (score 11):

#### Empty answers to questions requiring an interpreter

If a question asks for an implementation of a language or a machine, the language/machine itself is a terribly boring answer. In particular:

1. "Simulating" a machine on that machine by accepting the initial state as its own initial state and producing the final state as its own final state.
2. "Interpreting" a language using an empty program that "accepts input" as the rest (i.e., all) of what's fed to the interpreter.

Comment: What if your answer is “eval”?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye, then that's quite a boring answer, isn't it?

Comment: but does it fall under this loophole?

Answer (score 9):

## Bypassing [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) by storing data in the file name

[Consensus says that it is perfectly fine to store data in the file name as long as that is added to the byte count](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1072). However, this doesn't seem entirely appropriate in [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) questions, since it could bypass the restrictions.

An example (which is what spurred me to write this) is [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/221221/3) which was disqualified by the challenge author because the filename followed the restrictions and not the file content. I don't think this is the right approach. That answer was written in [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), a language where the program is often stored in the file name and the file itself is empty.

I think the best solution here is not actually to ban storing data in the file name for [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) challenges, which gives Pxem and some similar languages an inherent disadvantage, but instead to restrict submissions to one of:

- typical programs, where the filename doesn't matter, and the content adheres to the restrictions
- empty or functionally meaningless program content, but where the filename must adhere to the restrictions instead

There are still a few cases where this won't work (slashes and null bytes in Unix-like filesystems, and more on Windows), but I imagine we can just declare that as long as it works *in theory* it's fine.

Answer (score 6):

### Precomputing data (including compile-time computation) to achieve lower runtime in [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) challenges

Consider a challenge where solutions must print out as many Fibonacci numbers as possible within a certain time limit. A C++ solution might look like this:

```c++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 1, c = 0;
    while(true) {
        cout << b << endl;
        c = b;
        b = a+b;
        a = c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is a perfectly valid solution. All of the computation is done at runtime, and its score can be determined fairly.

Now, consider the following solution (adapted from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22645853/2508324)):

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;
template<uintmax_t N>
struct fibonacci : integral_constant<uintmax_t, fibonacci<N-1>{} + fibonacci<N-2>{}> {};

template<> struct fibonacci<1> : integral_constant<uintmax_t,1> {};
template<> struct fibonacci<0> : integral_constant<uintmax_t,0> {};

int main() {
    const uintmax_t max = 10000ull;
    cout << fibonacci<1>() << endl;
    cout << fibonacci<2>() << endl;
    cout << fibonacci<3>() << endl;
    // ...
    cout << fibonacci<10000>() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This program (compiled with `g++ -o template_fib template_fib.cpp -std=c++14 -ftemplate-depth=12257`) shifts the burden of computing the 10000 Fibonacci numbers to the compiler. At runtime, it's simply outputting 10000 constant values.

Such solutions which attempt to cheat the scoring system by doing all of the computation during a time where the clock is not running should either not be allowed, or be required to count their compilation time into their score.

[An actual example of this.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240758/100664)

Comment: Looks like a bad question to me. In most cases you could just also count the compile time for all submissions. But in your example, someone could just post a PHP or /// answer with the required output in it.

Comment: @jimmy23013 But there could be a legitimate solution that does all the work during runtime, but the compiler is woefully slow. We wouldn't want to penalize such a solution.

Comment: Do you have any examples of such a compiler?

Comment: I know that C++ itself could be slow if you use some libraries. But there are a lot of things that could be abused there. For example someone can write a compiler that automatically convert something like your first code to the second, and technically it could be just an optimization, without changing the semantics of the language. I'm thinking about something like limiting the size of the source code (if counting compile time) or the compiled code (if not counting compile time). Some questions already do, but I'm not sure it works for all cases.

Comment: Sorry, but I felt that I had to downvote this. As has already been mentioned, a compiler could easily do this optimisation itself, with the required flags of course. But in the example you've shown, it's just manually hard-coding the input using some syntactic sugar, and so it's barely different to `printf("1\n1\n2\n3\n5...");`.

Comment: It doesn't matter if its code or a compiler flag doing the storage.  Fundamentally, nearly all fastest-code challenges can be precompiled (if it takes input, you could simply precompile all possible input).  This *is* a loophole, and one we often have to say "don't do" in all fastest-code challenges.

Comment: This is an interesting point.  Hard-coding manually is one thing, but actually having the real work done at compile-time is another.  In the latter case, maybe you should count compile-time as part of the total run-time of the program.  This is mostly an issue with C++ template "metaprogramming".  Since C++ compilers use memoization instead of redoing recursive work every time, a dumb recursive algorithm implemented with template args can run *much* faster at compile time than the run-time performance of the same algo implemented in plain C.

Comment: In the case of large data, the size of a stripped binary executable (or at least its `text`+`data` segments) is a useful measure.  Getting the compiler to make a big table for you at compile-time has a run-time cost, but repeated runs (with the executable's pages hot in memory instead of cold on disk) doesn't reflect that.  Still, pre-computing (especially from compact and maintainable source) is a valid option for real programs.  Depending on the task, doing it at program-startup instead of compile-time is more appropriate, though, for a long-running program.

Comment: Also, sequential Fibonacci numbers is a poor example, unless you were showing a stupid recursive implementation.  Both of those will run at near-identical speeds, totally dominated by the `cout <<` function calls.  If anything, the loop might run faster on a modern x86 because it stays hot in the uop cache and branch predictors, instead of having to decode new `mov` and `call` instructions.  (Even unconditional direct branches like `call` need branch prediction to run efficiently.)

Comment: If you really wanted to optimize, you'd write code that turned into a string of multiple numbers and newlines at compile time.  *That* could really run fast, not requiring any integer->string conversions and only one I/O function call for a big block of data, and might actually have the run-time dominated by a write() system call, and/or soft page-faults reading the giant string.  Either way, printing `'\n'` instead of `std::endl` is probably faster (since it forces an extra flush), but printing multiple newlines at once is *way* faster on a line-buffered stream.

Comment: **TL:DR, the first version probably runs faster!**  Fully unrolling a loop that long is bad, especially with no loop-condition.

Comment: @PeterCordes The specific example isn't very important. The point is, fastest code challenges are timed based on runtime, which excludes compile time for compiled languages. Thus, solving the problem at compile time to get an extremely low run time is loophole abuse.

Comment: @Mego: I guess I'd agree with that, even if template metaprogramming to achieve that would be the right solution in a real program for that case.  The problem is that it's hard to state the rule in a way that blocks everything we want to block, but allows everything we want to allow.  (Analyzing the specific example was an interesting side-track, but ultimately irrelevant.  Still, since I don't think we can do much better than just knowing it when we see it, having the at-compile-time example do some string concatenating to beat the run-time version would be good.)

Comment: As other people have pointed out, pre-computing some quick things as part of a bigger algorithm is realistic.  It's only fully pre-computing the final answer that we probably must always disallow.  So the headline wording of this answer should be more specific.

Comment: So? Just count the compilation + execution time together. Problem solved. If a program solves exactly one instance of one problem, the compile time should be included. Why we don't care about what happens at compile time is that, usually, software is run many times for different problem instances, after being built once: compiling is a fixed cost.

Comment: @Kaz Having to count the compile time for a program that doesn't abuse this loophole would be unfair, since it's the compiler and not the specific program taking time.

Answer (score 6):

---

## Using a very high base (like base Graham’s number) in a challenge where you need to output a big number

---

In [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263991/117478), I just outputted 10, and claimed it was in base <kbd>number that is bigger than any number printed in the challenge by another submission</kbd>. And of course, this seems like cheating.

---

The answer has been deleted, so here is the exact answer, quoted. I had to change a bit of the markdown to fit it in a quote, but it looks the same.

> ## Vyxal, \$\operatorname g\left(f_{\varphi(1,0,0)+7}(256^{26})\right)\$ where \$\operatorname g(x) = x \uparrow^x x\$ (outputs in base \$\operatorname g\left(f_{\varphi(1,0,0)+7}(256^{26})\right) \times {10}^6\$), 10 bytes
>
> ```
> ››››››››››
> ```
>
> [Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLigLrigLrigLrigLrigLrigLrigLrigLrigLrigLoiLCIiLCIiXQ==)
>
> Non base-10 numbers haven't been banned... so we have a new winner!
>
> [Related comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/largest-number-printable/149781#comment34804_18028)

---

For context, [here is the question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18028/117478).

---

Answer (score 3):

### Infinite output programs that wouldn't give all output given infinite resources

Example, loophole-violating code to output all integers:

```
bigint i = 0;
for(;;) bigint_print(i++);
```

This would never output negative numbers, even given unlimited resources, so it does not fulfil the challenge's requirements. A program that does fulfil the requirements would be:

```
bigint i = 0;
for(;;) {
    bigint_print(i++);
    bigint_print(-i);
}
```

Comment: I think this needs some context.

Comment: @PeterTaylor https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51976966#51976966

Comment: I don't get it. The context looks like a bad joke, and responses to a bad joke don't seem like a sound basis for proposing standard loopholes.

Comment: I think infinite unordered output is a rare enough class of problem that it might be best to just leave it up to the the question to specify that ["Any \[element of the output\] must eventually be printed after a finite amount of time."](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/93441/85334)

Answer (score 3):

## Outputting a Lazy list/Lazy data type in [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) challenges

This just moves the computation to after runtime. For example, in Python, the code:

```python
def f():
    return 492084389428**209480438084, 6356425635**23984723879
```

takes a very long time to run. However, if you use the `yield` keyword to generate a Lazy List:

```python
def f():
    yield 492084389428**209480438084
    yield 6356425635**23984723879
```

it returns the result instantly, without computing it. However, when you iterate through it:

```python
x = f()
print(next(x))
print(next(x))
```

It takes a really long time, since the computation was moved here, after the runtime.

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12327/106545 "If this method is used in time-based challenges then the time required to resolve the final promise must be counted towards your score." Not quite a duplicate since generators and promises aren't quite the same thing.

Comment: @Bbrk24 I think they’re similar enough.

Answer (score 2):

## Cracking your own answer (including using an alt account) in a [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge.

It would just allow you to get a large number of points with no effort! Plus, it doesn’t even make any sense to do that.

Answer (score 1):

## Teaming up in a KOTH

Each KOTH bot must try for its own win. If a bot has logic that specifically benefits a different bot, *especially* a bot by the same author, that wouldn't be fair. Then you could "win" simply by submitting a large number of teaming bots.

Conversely, targeting a specific bot to hurt them is also unfair. Of course, efficient counter-play is part of any winning strategy, but long as you are targeting a range of bots and not anyone specific that is ok.

It is also OK if your winning strategy ends up benefiting some other bot without explicitly targeting it.

Examples that would violate this:

- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248557/91213

Comment: this feels like combining two separate answers; teaming up in a koth and specifically targeting another bot are completely different issues IMO. At the very least, the title of this post should reflect the full contents.

Answer (score -4):

## Using [non-programming languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/25180) <sup>(irrelevant to "golfing" languages)</sup>

Not to be confused with golfing languages. This loophole definitely has nothing to do with golfing languages.

> A purported programming language should be accepted as such if and only if it is capable of addition of natural numbers and primality testing of natural numbers.

Follow [the link](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/25180) for a more complete definition.

Related meta post: [Do submissions have to be answered with a programming language?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10421/25180)

That is, to use something that was not considered a programming language in our criteria. I don't think this was really forbidden before. So here is something everybody can vote.

If this is forbidden, you cannot use languages such as [HQ9+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/HQ9%2B) or [Text](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Text) in any challenges. You have to use the less familiar [Help, WarDoq!](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Help,_WarDoq!) or [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////) instead, in most cases, or simply cannot compete if your code involves some more creative features that nobody invented a rule-compliant counterpart of the language having them. In this way we could possibly encourage users to program, not to find something "creative" or obscure.

If not, you can use any language as long as the person who created a compiler or interpreter calls it a language, *unless* forbidden by other per site or per question rules. If there is a good reason to add this restriction (such as in some cops-and-robbers questions), you should specify that explicitly. If the term "programming language" is mentioned somewhere, by default, it refers to languages satisfying our criteria.

Comment: This was always forbidden (at least as long as we had criteria for what constitutes a programming language), but it doesn't hurt to have it restated here IMO.

Comment: I once saw an [answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57617/is-this-number-a-prime/65859#65859) that was an Excel formula. Would this invalidate that answer?

Comment: @micsthepick No. Added the definition to this post.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Why? Http is not programming language, but do ypu think [this answer](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/56018/32091) is bad?

Comment: @Qwertiy I personally don't like banning this. But before this post people were already assuming they were forbidden.

Comment: @Qwertiy, yes. This is a site for programming contests. Answers should be programs, not data. Answering with HTTP headers on the basis that you can view the output in Firefox makes no more sense than answering with a Word document on the basis that you can view the output in Word.

Comment: I think answers which use things like HQ9+ should be allowed but not compete.

Comment: HTML+CSS would fail this definition, but they often make interesting solutions to challenges.

Comment: There should be a mention here that the linked meta post entirely supersedes this.

Comment: I don't think that meta post supersedes this. The score (+35/-25) is not high enough to be considered consensus, but if this were to get 15 more upvotes I don't see why that wouldn't mean that the community has changed its mind about whether to allow solutions in non-programming languages.

Comment: @SteveBennett [HTML and CSS are turing complete](https://accodeing.com/blog/2015/css3-proven-to-be-turing-complete).

Comment: Heh, that doesn't seem like an accurate summary of what you linked.

Answer (score -4):

## Storing information in type of input

Imagine a language with billions kinds of arrays and you choose one type as input to do the job, which is silly

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12271/76323)

Comment: Do you have an example post where this is (ab)used?

Comment: @Mast As mentioned in chat I don't know any language that doing this is good, it's only preventing

Comment: If it hasn't happened yet, forbidding it seems premature to me.

Comment: Maybe, [someone](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24066/) delete theirs but I'd just leave this here

Comment: I can't even comprehend this suggestion.

Answer (score -6):

## A script invoking itself as a form of looping/recursion, where the filename has to be a specific name

e.g. I answered a question with PowerShell which included `sleep 1;t` where the script had to be called `t.ps1` and saved in the PATH, so it would call itself.

I considered it maybe reasonable because running programs is part of what shell scripts do, and there's no reference to it in this meta topic as a standard loophole. The closest is about [hiding information in the filename, e.g. a file called "hello world"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1072/571).

People commented to say relying on the filename is frowned upon, so I'm submitting it here so it can be voted on and be on record as approved/denied in future. Is it a loophole, or is it valid in the same way as an answer might say "requires version 3 or above" or "only works in a particular interpreter"?

Comment: I don't think requiring a specific filename is a problem in general, unless this is abused to hide code or store information in the filename. For example, every full Java program requires a specific filename for compilation.

Comment: @Dennis But that is also a requirement of the language - using it explicitly for purposes other than compiling seems a bit loophole-y.

Comment: If it is _not_ considered a loophole, then the filename should also be counted in the byte count.

Comment: The filename is counted, `t` in the script is the filename. if you had a bash script which called `sed` would you count `sed` as 3 more characters as well as it appearing in the script? It's also relying on a particular program with a particular filename being in the PATH.

Comment: Then you'd need to count the `t` in the code and the `t.ps1` in the filename - if you changed either of these, it wouldn't function, would it?

Comment: @FlagAsSpam I fail to see why we would count `t.ps1` as 5 bytes, yet `t.java` as 0 bytes, especially since this seems to be the most natural form of recursion for PowerShell.

Comment: @Dennis You _need_ to call it in Java, because that's how the language works. Recursion can be called via other methods in PowerShell, as shown by another answer in the same question.

Comment: @FlagAsSpam If we're talking about the same answer, it uses a for loop, not recursion. In any case, I could get behind a convention that counts `t.ps1` as *one* byte (for the `t`), since the rest is just the typical PowerShell extension.

Comment: For a sed script which requires a flag, the flag must be counted in the byte count because it's a required extra to make the answer work. But it's not possible to save a script with no filename, so I'm not mandating *extra* information, so why would it count extra? You always need a filename ending in `.ps1` for a PS script, constraining what the filename can be doesn't add any extra bytes. (@Dennis, I partly deleted my answer because it would eventually overflow - but I also wonder about that - usable answers which would eventually hit real world limits are sometimes allowed).

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I don't think we have a default for that. The best option is to ask the OP in a comment. (Note that `exec $0` in Bash should *not* have the same limitation, since `exec` *replaces* the current shell with another one.)

Answer (score -11):

## Builtins in [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) challenges that solve the challenge completely

I know [we don't like disallowing builtins](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1078/107299), but having a builtin in a [sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) challenge solve the entire thing is a bit too much. While it's be nice to add it as a side note, show off what your language can do!

Answer (score -17):

## Using comments to circumvent character requirements/restrictions

It's cute and makes you laugh once, but when you see it several times over several challenges, it just becomes facetious and contrary to the spirit of the game.

Example: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12370/5358

Comment: I think that's actually a good answer for that question

Comment: @SztupY It's clever, and I laughed about it and upvoted it.  But it is against the "spirit" of the question, and this kind of thing is done in lots of places.

Comment: It's funny once. But I agree, if you post something like that challenge, you should forbid comments. (If someone does not, leave a link to this answer).

Comment: @JeffGohlke Actually, for that particular question, it's completely fair game - but sadly it's not the shortest by a long shot.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I don't think comments was a big concern with that question, since the comments don't make it trivial. You still need to be printing characters without using them.

Comment: Perhaps "don't submit a program without any code" is what you mean

Comment: As I told in some comment, my answer should be the worst possible answer. And funnily some people even posted longer answers.

Comment: I am strongly against this; this means that there is something wrong with the question, not the answer.

Answer (score -31):

### Sending error messages to the null device

... instead of avoiding them.

This should either be forbidden or add to the byte count, as setting options to suppress messages do.

[example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94852#94852)

Comment: I don't think this is a loophole. Since [STDERR is ignored by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4781/42963), the example provided looks to just be a way to prettify the output.

Comment: @TimmyD That I didn´t know until now. Hey and I wasted tons of bytes to code around warnings. :D I still find it ... confusing that error messages are allowed; but if those are the rules: so be it.

Comment: Nitpick: Warnings aren't error messages.

Answer (score -44):

### Compressing your source code

Some language provide builtin facilities to compress data and execute the result as source code. I consider this to be a standard loophole, especially when the challenge is counted in characters instead of bytes.

Comment: This can be argued and extended to many other built-ins. Like Mathemetica's built in `MandelbrotSetPlot` to plot a mandelbrot set. I think the practice of questions themselves explicitly disallowing such compressions is the most favorable scenario and holds true for any such built-in, not just code compression ones

Comment: I do not think that this is a loophole. The default scoring is in bytes for good reason. If a challenge author deviates, then I'd assume they have a good reason for doing so.

Comment: In addition, if you're doing a kolmogorov-complexity challenge in a language like ///, the only way to be competitive whatsoever is to compress the source code. If you can find a way to encode and then `eval` your code so that it's shorter than the normal algorithm, than good for you.

Answer (score -61):

## Using built-in functions to do the work

Mathematica is a big one for this, with `Fibonacci[n]` to calculate the `n`'th Fibonacci number....  I have no objection to these being posted as a side note within the main answer though - that is interesting and helps me learn different languages capabilities.

Another one that encounters this more often than most is with Assembly, especially with questions requiring bitwise-related operations, such as ARM's `rbit` reversing the bits in place or Haswell's `pext` to extract bits according to a mask.

Comment: Or using `CellularAutomaton` to [implement a Game of Life](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3513212/10396)

Comment: I think this only applies when the main part of the question is for the function.

Comment: @Quincunx Yes, I know.  Still...

Comment: Perhaps if it were qualified with "lion's share of the work". Fibonacci[n] to solve a Fibonacci problem is bad form, but there are also plenty of instances of high-level stats/graphics/maths functions in R, Processing, Mathematica, etc. being used in the context of good answers. It's hard to define objectively the line between good answer playing to the language's strengths and lazy answer plastering over the answerer's weakness. But you generally know it when you see it.

Comment: If we were all limited to the same set of built-in functions, every contest would be won by APL or Golfscript because their command names are the shortest.

Comment: @MichaelStern I mean that if the challenge is to implement a function, we shouldn't just give a function that was already implemented into the source of your language.

Comment: I believe one purpose of code golf is to display features, especially obscure ones, of a language, but I still agree they should be disallowed.

Comment: Contrarily, I think using built-in functions is good. It highlights the benefits of different languages.

Comment: I made an edit to include the increasing prevalence of assembly built-ins under the same umbrella here.

Comment: What if, in a certain language, there's no work to be done to solve a problem? For example, for a snippet, by receiving the input the result is already calculated? That's what I ran into for [my AVR answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/43168/34744)

Comment: @rsaxvc I do not know.  You will have to ask a question about this.

Comment: @daviewales maybe as a side note, but not for the real golf.

Comment: These are only a problem when the challenge states you can't use those builtins. Using built-in `rand()` in some languages (i.e, Perl, C) is OK.

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of built in functions, though? I mean I thought the whole idea behind programming was to not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Only when the challenge is not about writing a random number generator.  Otherwise, it would be like saying `Oh, I'd like to to get my name here, but I don't really care about the challenge."

Comment: @tfitzger Real programming, yes.  This site is about having fun and solving problems (even if they are already solved), not so much about programming to be productive.

Comment: @Hosch250 Then it should be up to the poster to determine what level of function answers can contain. Technically, most of the answers on this site rely on functions, routines, subroutines, etc to get their answer. Some can just do it in one or two instead of twelve of fifteen. I've seen posts limit the use of min or max functions, use of inherent random functions, use of mod, etc. There, the person asking the question was responsible for deciding the level of function that was allowed.

Comment: There was a [question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90189/49439) that required the computation of the Kolmogorov—Smirnov statistic. It is a built-in in R that requires no extra packages, so why should I re-invent the wheel? Forcing to re-implement the intrinsic features of a language in the same language seems futile to me.

Comment: Here's another great Mathematica one: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86963/73884

Comment: Banning built-ins is like banning golfing languages; it is done out of annoyance and there is no formal definition of a builtin